# How to modify a model with ApplicationRecord for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to understand why my upload application in Ruby on Rails is returning this error unknown attribute 'file' for Document
I'm trying to build an upload app for csv documents only.
The app it is using an external Gem for doing the upload:
[Gem](https://github.com/Jakub41/csv_uploader_widget)

My controller where the error occurs:

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_document, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /documents
  # GET /documents.json
  def index
    @documents = Document.all
  end

  # GET /documents/1
  # GET /documents/1.json
  def show
    send_data(@document.file_contents,
              type: @document.content_type,
              filename: @document.filename)
  end

  # GET /documents/new
  def new
    @document = Document.new
  end

  # GET /documents/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /documents
  # POST /documents.json
  def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.save
        format.html { redirect_to documents_path, notice: 'Document was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @document }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /documents/1
  # PATCH/PUT /documents/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.update(document_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @document, notice: 'Document was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @document }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /documents/1
  # DELETE /documents/1.json
  def destroy
    @document.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to documents_url, notice: 'Document was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_document
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def document_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:file)
  end
end
```

The controller should hold the creat upload functionality and upload using as a reference the external Gem for make the file upload.

The model where I' calling some functionality from the Gem:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CsvUploaderWidget
  validate :file_size_under_one_mb, :csv_file_format
  before_save :upload_local
end
```

Comment: when you do `@document = Document.new(document_params)`, you're trying to create a `Document` instance, and `document_params` has a key called `file`, so, that line is trying to assign whatever comes in the `params[:document][:file]` to an attribute called `file` in your `@document` instance, and since you haven't defined an attribute with that name in your `Document` class, that line fails. Just add `attr_accessor :file` in your `Document` class.

Comment: Do u field called file in Document model.?